# ckeditor + hide & show of contenteditable + unable to edit

Tags: webkit, ckeditor

crosspost:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/inline-editor-div-contenteditable-when-loaded-hidden-doesnt-work.

when you try to attach ckeditor to hidden contenteditable and then make it visible the ckeditor is disabled & the div is contenteditable=false

adding below css did not help much

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write;
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show what you already tried? If `contenteditable=false` then editor is in readonly mode. Change the value of this attribute and editor will be editable if it can be initialised on hidden elements (I'm not sure about that).

If it cannot be initialised on hidden container - initialise it after showing it and destroy before hiding it. But again - `contenteditable` needs to be set to `true`.